# gitconfig ignoring includeIf

Tags: git, github, git-config

I am trying to set up my git config so that I can use a work environment and a personnal environment.

Here is the contents of my `~.gitconfig` file (it so happens work and private are on github):

```
 [url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
 [core]
    editor = vim
 [includeIf "gitdir:~/go/src/github.com/work/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-work
 [includeIf "gitdir:~/go/src/github.com/fzd/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-private
```

Here are the contents of both files :

```sh
> cat ~/.gitconfig-work
[user]
    email = workerID@company.com
    name = realname
    signingkey = 454684684654...
[commit]
    gpgSign = true

> cat ~/.gitconfig-private
[user]
    email = fzd@email.com
    name = fzd
```

Now let's wander to one of these directories :

```sh
> cd ~/go/src/github.com/work/
> git config --get user.email  
> 

> cd ~/go/src/github.com/fzd/
> git config --get user.name
>
```

None of the above returned a string.

I was expecting this to work (and it would have solved my troublesome git configuration).

Now, the "fun" part: This config was initially my work config, with only work set properly.
When I try to clone a repo from github, wherever I am, it's using my work settings (I haven't restarted since I tried messing around with git - I suppose it's  not yet worth it).

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong with my config ? And why is it using the work parameters ? Is there a kind of cache over the git config ?

[edit]
Here are the contents of my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```sh
 Host github.com
     Hostname ssh.github.com
     Port 443
 
 Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 10
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_work
```

I do have a key pair for the private repos, I'm not entirely sure how to have both here. Probably something like [this](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/using-multiple-ssh-keys-for-multiple-github-accounts/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`includeIf` works only in **repositories** under `~/go/src/github.com/work/` and `~/go/src/github.com/fzd/` but not in a non-repo directory.

To test:

```
cd ~/go/src/github.com/work/<some-repo>
git config --get user.email
```

Comment: This works fine for the `work` repos I had previously. Maybe the problem is that, now, I want to clone a repo in `~/go/src/github.com/fzd/` using fzd@email.com without writing it on the command-line. Is it doable ?
It would be my only way of checking I'm getting different values in other repos than the work repos. [[When I try to clone a work repo in `.../fzd`, this works well and it uses my work id]]

Comment: When you clone a repo `user.name`/`user.email` are **not used** at all. These config settings are only used when you **create a new commit**. But they are not credentials, they're not used to authenticate, they're not used while cloning. After cloning `cd` to the new repo and test `git config --get user.email`

Comment: Right. We're progressing. I can indeed successfully clone my work repos on one side, my private repos on the other... but there's still one that I can't clone, even though I can access it on the github website. I think this issue is solved, thanks a lot ! I'll try and understand what's going on with the other one -- and that's the one I've been using to check if it worked :(