# git clone via https when using multiple accounts

Tags: git

I use multiple github accounts and have setup a global `.gitconfig` which includes

```
[user]
    name = Private Name
...
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Work/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-work
```

whereas `~/.gitcofig-work` contains configs for a work account.

This works well whenever I'm *inside* of a git-repo. If the repo is located somewhere inside `~/Work/` git will use my work credentials and otherwise my personal ones.
But when I want to clone a repo, and thus being *outside* of a git repo, this does not kick in and the wrong credentials are used.

I'm using https and stored access tokens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474438/7976758 That how it works — only in repositories but not in the root directory if the root dir is not a repo itself. Perhaps you can use `mkdir newrepo && cd newrepo && git init && git remote add origin URL && git fetch && git checkout master` instead of `git clone`.

Comment: I guess I'm stubborn and thought it _should_ work. That is a decent workaround. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like I additionally need to include the correct username in the remote url with this workaround. As in `git remote add origin https://username@github.com/...`. I'm still not sure when things work and when not.

Answer (score 0):

As [phd noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73393193/git-clone-via-https-when-using-multiple-accounts#comment129611406_73393193), this is how it's defined now.  I think it's something of a bug that `git clone` doesn't apply the rule "as if" the new repository had been created *in* the target directory "before" the rule that changes the way Git works once it *is* in the target directory, but making this happen inside the Git code is nontrivial.

(It would be so much easier if `git clone` were still a shell script....)

Another potential workaround is to create a dummy top level repository in `~/Work` just so that it *is* a Git repository.

Comment: I've never used nested git repos, mainly because the intuition/prejudice that it probably is messy. Perhaps it isn't as bad as I think... You don't anticipate any issues or deviations from "normal stand-alone git repos"  with this?

Comment: Repositories don't actually get nested until you `git add` a submodule (so don't do that) or `git submodule add` one (so don't do that either). So the point of the dummy top level repository would be just to make Git apply the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus answer! I'll certainly test this approach.