# How do I set my git config so it automatically uses my work email and personal email for work and personal repos?

Tags: git

I have a dozen work repos in ~/source/repos/work and a dozen personal repos in ~/source/repos/mine. When I commit personal code on github.com I want it to use my personal email. When I submit code at work I want it to use my work email.

I know I can configure this by having a .gitconfig in my home directory with my personal email address and adding my work email address to .git/config on all dozen work repos. But I want something easier and less error-prone. I might blow away a repo once a week and re-clone it. I will often forget to set my work email for each repo when I do this.

Is there a way that the proper email address can be inferred from the path to the repo? The ideal would be a .gitconfig that I could put in ~/source/repos/work that contains my work address. Then any repo made below work/ would have the contents of work/.gitconfig applied to it, after applying ~/.gitconfig but before that repo's config.

This functionality exists for Perforce with .p4config.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/7976758 But please be warned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474438/7976758